# Java Random between 1, 2 and 3

Tags: java, loops, random

Not able to get three integers

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Random rand = new Random(3)+1;
    if (rand == 1){
        hand.takeCard(one);
    } else if (rand == 2){
        hand.takeCard(two);
    } else if (rand == 3){
        hand.takeCard(three);
    }
}
```

How do I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Comparing a reference type to a primitive type with `==` will not compile (in this case).

Comment: Please read the doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: `new Random(3)` doesn't do what you think it does. Read the docs for `Random`.

Comment: Trying to add cards in a hand. If 1, add card one, if 2, add card 2 etc.

Comment: Use Random's [nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method...

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Random.nextInt(int n)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed **int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)**, drawn from this random number generator's sequence

### Sample usage

```
int rand = new Random().nextInt(3);
System.out.println(i);
```

In your case:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    int rand = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;
    if (rand == 1){
        hand.takeCard(one);
    } else if (rand == 2){
        hand.takeCard(two);
    } else if (rand == 3){
        hand.takeCard(three);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int myNumber=0;//create integer that holds your generated number
   Random rand = new Random(); //create random number generator
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

                   myNumber=rand.nextInt(3);//this assign a new random value to your integerrandom generator is 0 based so you generate numbers 0,1,2 if you put 3 as parameter.Bud you can fix that by adding + 1 to it after closing brackets or just put 0for your first card
            if (myNumber== 0){
                hand.takeCard(one);
            } else if (myNumber== 1){
                hand.takeCard(two);
            } else if (myNumber== 2){
                hand.takeCard(three);
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Note that you're generating a random number between 0 and 2.

Comment: It worked, thanks. But made a change, instead of nyNumber == 1 used myNumber == 0, decremented each and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
       if (rand == 1){
                hand.takeCard(one);
            } else if (rand == 2){
                hand.takeCard(two);
            } else if (rand == 3){
                hand.takeCard(three);
            } 
       }
```